# How to specify the database when registering a data frame to a table in Spark1.6

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a simple Spark script, and running into issues putting data where I want to, and getting the job to work.  Specifically, I need to specify the database of the tables when registering a data frame to a temp table.

```
    df_del_records,df_add_records,df_exclusion_records=get_new_records(dff)
    df_del_records.registerTempTable("db.update_deletes_temp_table")
    df_add_records.registerTempTable("db.update_adds_temp_table")
    df_exclusion_records.registerTempTable("db.exclusions_temp_table")
    sqlContext.sql("insert overwrite table db.automated_quantity_updates select * from db.update_deletes_temp_table")
    sqlContext.sql("insert into table db.automated_quantity_updates select * from db.update_adds_temp_table")
    sqlContext.sql("insert into table db.exclusions select * from db.exclusions_temp_table")
```

The code above runs without errors, but does not yield any results.  Removing the database yields results, but that won't work in production where the database in which the temp tables have to be stored is not whatever default Spark is using.  How do I specify which database a temp table needs to be in registering a datagrame to a temp table in Spark 1.6?

Comment: First, what type of database are you going to use? As Spark defaults database is on top of anything that is a metadata stored in your HDFS. Can be hive or other stuffs. If its going to be other database you should look for the connections that can be done with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The temporary table/view which is created by `registerTempTable` or `createOrReplaceTempView` is not related to any databases. It just creates a view of the dataframe with a query plan based on how the dataframe was created.

From [Apache Spark's Dataset.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2840)

> Local temporary view is session-scoped. Its lifetime is the lifetime of the session that created it, i.e. it will be automatically dropped when the session terminates. It's not tied to any databases, i.e. **we can't use `db1.view1` to reference a local temporary view**.

<sub>emphasis added by me.</sub>